# Why printf is c is producing this output

Tags: c

This is my following code in C

```
printf("%d %f\n",4,4);
```

**Output**

```
4 0.000000
```

Why does printf produce this output instead of 4.000000 in second place?

Comment: It shouldn't. There must be some other relevant code here that you aren't showing.

Comment: I tried it in visual studio with only printf statement.

Answer (score 6):

4 is an integer and not a float. You should use:

```
printf("%d %f\n",4,4.);
```

where the second number is a double (or float) value.

Comment: Using `4.0` in place of `4.` would make the float-ness of the last argument more obvious. That `.` is easy to miss.

Answer (score 5):

It's [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C. N1570 (C11 draft) `7.21.6.1/9` *The fprintf function*:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for
>   the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

The `%f` format specifier is designated for `float` or `double` values (due to fact, that `printf()` is variadic function, thus *default argument promotions* apply to it) and `4` is integer constant of type `int`.

Valid example calls:

```
printf("%d %f\n", 4, 4.0);
```

or

```
printf("%d %f\n", 4, 4.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have lied to `printf`.  As you've used the `%f` format specifier, you have promised to pass a floating point value.  However, your second argument is of integral type.  This invokes undefined behavior which might result in what you are seeing.

To correct this, either use `%d` as format specifier or change the second argument to `4.0`.

A good compiler can help you detect such bugs.  Please try turning on warnings. (For GCC, `-Wall` would have told you about the problem.)

Why is this so?  Normally, if we call a function that expects a `double` with `4` as its argument, the compiler will implicitly convert that `int` to a `double`.  However, for a variadric function such as `printf` is one, the language says that such conversion does not happen.  Actually, it *cannot* happen because `printf` accepts arguments of multiple types so to what type should they be converted?  (The only thing that happens is *promotion*.  For example, `4.0f` would promote to a `double`.)  It is the responsibility of the programmer to do the type conversion beforehand in this case.  (The reason GCC can warn about the wrong type is that it parses the format string and – since `printf` is a standard function – understands what it means.  The language does not require this.)

Answer (score 2):

Because the call of the function has undefined behaviour.

Accordint to the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function - the same is valid for printf)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.275) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

And

> **f,F A double argument representing a floating-point number** is
>   converted to decimal notation in the style [−]ddd.ddd, where the
>   number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the
>   precision specification.

You are using format specifier `%f` with argument of type `int` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you pass an integer as an argument to a function, if that argument is supposed to be a floating-point number (according to the function's prototype), the compiler automatically converts it to a floating-point quantity for you.

However, `printf` (and all other functions that take a variable number of arguments) do not specify the expected types of the arguments covered by the `...` in the prototype.  Therefore, the compiler does not do any automatic conversion.  (It does something else, called *default argument promotion*, instead.)

So when you call `printf("%f", 4)`, the compiler passes the 4 as an `int`, but `printf` looks for a `double`.  This mismatch triggers *undefined behavior* -- anything at all could happen.

Nowadays, many compilers can parse the `printf` format string and *warn* you when the argument types don't match up with the format string, and so they *could* insert conversion code as appropriate (undefined behavior includes "it works exactly as intended on THIS system") but they generally don't, because you should fix your code so it works as intended on *all* compilers rather than just those that are being extra helpful.

Writing `printf("%f", 4.0)` or `printf("%f", (double)int_variable)` is sufficient to correct your code.